# Causes of gzopen() leading to ENOMEM

Tags: zlib, enomem

I have a program whose total memory footprint is about 100 MiB (VM size, in top, while stopped in `gdb`) that's trying to open a new (not-yet-existent) compressed log file using `gzopen`. This fails, with `errno` set to `ENOMEM`, despite the fact that the system has 6GB memory completely free (not even holding caches), and lots of space on the filesystem (that would be `ENOSPC`, I know). Are there more obscure issues that could cause this? Is something in the library incidentally allocating gigabytes upon gigabytes of memory for no good reason?

For note, my ulimits are set unlimited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out zlib was not returning `ENOMEM`. It was bailing out because we had passed it a mode argument `w+`, which is invalid because it can't read and write a given gzip file at the same time. The `ENOMEM` came from what happened to be sitting in `errno` from previous library/system calls.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing in zlib that would allocate more than a MiB or two.  zlib will only set errno to zero.  On its own, it never sets errno to ENOMEM.  The library functions it calls may.  What version of zlib are you using?